# Wordpress contact form 7 indian 10 digit phone number validation

Tags: wordpress

I want to validate "contact form 7" Indian 10 digit phone number validation without the plugin.

Below is the pattern I used in the plugin:

So, in the Contact Form 7 formatting.php module I changed like this but still, it is not validating:

```
function wpcf7_is_tel( $tel ) {
    $result = preg_match( '/^[+]?[0-10() -]*$/', $tel );
    return apply_filters( 'wpcf7_is_tel', $result, $tel );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, in the Contact Form 7 formatting.php module,

```
function wpcf7_is_tel( $tel ) {
    $result = preg_match( '/^[+]?[0-9() -]*$/', $tel );
    return apply_filters( 'wpcf7_is_tel', $result, $tel );
}
```

replace with add pattern line      /^([1]-)?[0-9]{10}$/i

```
function wpcf7_is_tel( $tel ) {
        $result = preg_match( '/^([1]-)?[0-9]{10}$/i', $tel );  // added line
        return apply_filters( 'wpcf7_is_tel', $result, $tel );
    }
```

Note: it accept maximum 10 digits

Comment: in addition of this answer, I recommend to test regex before to use it. this can be done here e.g. https://regex101.com/r/ueX5OD/2

Answer (score 1):

this should do the trick

```
function wpcf7_is_tel( $tel ) {
        $result = preg_match( '^\d{10}$/i', $tel );  // added line
        return apply_filters( 'wpcf7_is_tel', $result, $tel );
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @lvollmer. The above pattern doesn't work. But this pattern worked for me---->   /^([1]-)?[0-9]{10}$/i